# jQuery Masked Input (digitalBush) doesn't work with Chrome 19 input type="number"

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, maskedinput

I am trying to use jQuery Masked Input (from digitalBush) without success. My HTML code is:

```
<input class="numeric float optional" id="ocorrencia_altura" min="0" name="ocorrencia[altura]" step="any" type="number">
```

And my Javascript code is:

```
$("#ocorrencia_altura").mask("9,99");
```

It works fine in Firefox 12 (field without spins (HTML5 input type=number)) but doesn't work with Chrome 19, where the input has spins. I can't even insert a number in Chrome (In text fields it works). How could I fix this?

Comment: you may visit this link https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/pull/85; this might help you as type = number or tel is having masking problem

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a ? at the start of the mask specifier:

```
$("#ocorrencia_altura").mask("?9,99");
```